# Bad Substitution - Variable name inside other variable name - in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a problem in one of my scripts, here it is simplified.
I want to name a variable using another variable in it. My script is:

```
#! /bin/bash
j=1
SAMPLE${j}_CHIP=5
echo ${SAMPLE${j}_CHIP}
```

This script echoes:

```
line 3: SAMPLE1_CHIP=5: command not found
line 4: ${SAMPLE${j}_CHIP}: bad substitution
```

I'm trying to do that in order to name several samples in a while loop changing the "j" parameter.
Anyone knows how to name a variable like that?

Comment: Are you planning to use a variable context or an array context in `bash`?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with `eval`, but don't use dynamic variable names. Arrays are much, much better.

```
$ j=1
$ SAMPLES[j]=5
$ echo ${SAMPLES[j]}
5
```

You can initialize an entire array at once like so:

```
$ SAMPLES=(5 10 15 20)
```

And you can append with:

```
$ SAMPLES+=(25 30)
```

Indices start at 0.

Comment: But what I want is name the variable "SAMPLES_CHIP1" and save in it a value in order to introduce this variable as an input parameter in other script

Comment: What you "want" is a security and maintainability nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

To read the value of the variable, you may use indirection: `${!var}`:

```
#! /bin/bash
j=1
val=get_5
var=SAMPLE${j}_CHIP

declare "$var"="$val"

echo "${!var}"
```

The problem is to make the variable get the value.
I used declare above, and the known options are:

```
declare "$var"="$val"
printf -v "$var" '%s' "$val"
eval $var'=$val'
export "$var=$val"
```

The most risky option is to use eval. If the contents of `var` or `val` may be set by an external user, you have set a way to get code injection. It may seem safe today, but after someone edit the code for some reason, it may get changed to give an attacker a chance to "get in".

Probably the best solution is to avoid all the above.

## Associative Array

One alternative is to use Associative Arrays:

```
#! /bin/bash
j=1
val=get_5
var=SAMPLE${j}_CHIP
declare -A array

array[$var]=$val
echo "${array[$var]}"
```

Quite less risky and you get a similar named index.

## Plain array

But it is clear that the safest solution is to use the simplest of solutions:

```
#! /bin/bash
j=1
val=get_5

array[j]=$val
echo "${array[j]}"
```

All done, little risk.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use variable variables:

```
#! /bin/bash
j=1
var="SAMPLE${j}_CHIP"
export ${var}=5
echo "${!var}" # prints 5
```

However, there are other approaches to solving the parent issue, which are likely less confusing than this approach.

Comment: echo "${!var}" doesn't work on Mac OS when the script is sourced, but it can be executed normally.  Is there an alternative when being sourced we can use to evaluate the variable?

Comment: What about using a hash / associative array? Something like `SAMPLES_CHIP[${var}]=5` ... or are you setting variables to be used by something else and you can't change the something else? ... Issac's answer was the best.

Comment: I have a need to source environment vars this way, so an associative array won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
j=1
eval "SAMPLE${j}_CHIP=5" 
echo "${SAMPLE1_CHIP}"
```

Or

```
j=1
var="SAMPLE${j}_CHIP"
eval "$var=5" 
echo "${!var}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, it's normally not possible. Here is a workaround if you wish. Note that you have to use eval when declaring a nested variable, and ⭗ instead of $ when accessing it (I use ⭗ as a function name, because why not).

```
#!/bin/bash
function ⭗ {
    if [[ ! "$*" = *\{*\}* ]]
    then echo $*
    else ⭗ $(eval echo $(echo $* | sed -r 's%\{([^\{\}]*)\}%$(echo ${\1})%'))
    fi
}
j=1
eval SAMPLE${j}_CHIP=5
echo `⭗ {SAMPLE{j}_CHIP}`
c=CHIP
echo `⭗ {SAMPLE{j}_{c}}`
```